# Why are jelly donuts usually raspberry flavored

Tags: baking, doughnuts

Why are jelly donuts filled with raspberry flavored jelly unless specified otherwise.  There are lemon filled, strawberry filled, etc but if you just ask for a "jelly donut" it will be raspberry filled.

Comment: I can't imagine this is true worldwide (and I've never heard of it); where are you?

Comment: Welcome to the site brian! This is a fun question. I also wonder where you live. In my area of the Northeast United States a jelly doughnut is usually grape, though it does depend on the store. I think the berry fillings, like raspberry and strawberry, are technically jams, but that's a different subject!

Comment: I've always thought it was because artificial raspberry goo tasted closest to the real thing.

Answer (score 4):

I think this might actually be a regional thing. In my area, we're more likely to get blueberry or apple jelly doughnuts. It's probably got to do with whatever fruit is cheapest to use in large quantities for the location where the doughnuts are being made.

Comment: Strawberries - unless it is artificial strawberry flavor - are far from a cheap option...

Comment: @rackandboneman Not necessarily, if you're living in an area where they grow massive amounts of strawberries.

Comment: Or even something to do with seasons, or other elements of timing... whatever's generously available when making the batches, or when they're grabbing the doughnuts to sell them, gets given to whoever didin't specify a preference, so there's more of the less-available ones for those who *do* have a preference.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberries and Strawberries tend to pair well with rich, fat-bearing components, since their strong aroma and mild acidity tends to "cut through" the richness - you will find many examples of them served with rich ingredients like cream, whipped cream, ice cream, yoghurt or in this case, fried dough...